# How do I get screen resolution in a shell script on Linux

Tags: linux, function, shell, screen-resolution, dash-shell

### Environment

System: Linux Mint 18 / 19 Cinnamon 64-bit.

Shell: [`dash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) ([POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)).

---

### Question

I need to dynamically account for the screen resolution in a POSIX shell script.

I prefer a function for re-use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Function

```
get_screen_resolution()
{
    xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions:/ { print $2 }'
}
```

### Usage

```
resolution=$(get_screen_resolution)
```